# Print Word & Line Number Where Word Occurs in File Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to print the word and line number(s) where the word occurs in the file in Python. Currently I am getting the correct numbers for second word, but the first word I look up does not print the right line numbers. **I** **must** iterate through infile, use a dictionary to store the line numbers, remove new line chars, remove any punctuation & skip over blank lines when pulling the number. I need to add a value that is actually a list, so that I may add the line numbers to the list if the word is contained on multiple lines.

Adjusted code:

```
def index(f,wordf):

    infile = open(filename, 'r')
    dct = {}
    count = 0
    for line in infile:
        count += 1
        newLine = line.replace('\n', ' ')
        if newLine == ' ':
            continue
        for word in wordf:
            if word in split_line:
                if word in dct:
                    dct[word] += 1
                else:
                    dct[word] = 1

    for word in word_list:
        print('{:12} {},'.format(word,dct[word]))
    infile.close()
```

Current Output:

```
>>> index('leaves.txt',['cedars','countenance'])
pines        [9469, 9835, 10848, 10883],
counter      [792, 2092, 2374],
```

Desired output:

```
>>> index2('f.txt',['pines','counter','venison'])
pines       [530, 9469, 9835, 10848, 10883]
counter     [792, 2092, 2374]
```

Comment: My desired input is truncated for ease of understanding. However, I just noticed that the current output is actually pulling the instances in which the word appears in the file. Which means, that I am either not properly incrementing or adding the line number to the dictionary.

Comment: you still need to change the 'word' to 'word2' in the third loop, and it's associated places that use 'word2', otherwise it certainly won't work, see my post below

Comment: Are you running it in the IDE (or other executable variation)? It does not quite matter if you change word to word 2 in this case, and when you do with the last variation of the code, you would get an error. Like I said the last code, in any case, does not pull the line numbers, it pulls something else.

Comment: for word2 in split_line:                  if word2 == word: 
      
this is the part you need.
The current code you have won't have a use for 'word2' without the comparison after it, and you didn' have 'word2' when you had the comparison up

Comment: When I adjust the code to be reflective of word2 in the third for loop, the code does not print out the line number instances of the word.

Comment: even with the additional comparison after it?

Comment: Yes. I am not quite sure why.

Comment: I'm adding a new 'answer', because it's way easier than commenting in a comment. note: I literally copy pasted my post, then edited so I don't need to read from a file or worry about punctuation

Answer (score 0):

There is some ambiguity for how your file is set up, but I think it understand.
Try this:

```
import numpy as np # add this import
...

    for word in word_f:
        if word in split_line:

            np_array = np.array(split_line)
            item_index_list = np.where(np_array == word)

            dct[word] = item_index_list # note, you might want the 'index + 1' instead of the 'index'

for word in word_f:
    print('{:12} {},'.format(word,dct[word]))
...
```

btw, as far as I can tell, you're not using your 'increment' variable.

I think that'll work, let me know if it doesn't and I'll fix it

Comment: Thank you for your assistance! Would you have any thoughts on working through it without any imports? I am really trying to understanding how to iterate through a file and add increment to the dictionary fundamentally. Right now, I do think that what you have pointed out about me not using the increment variable is probably one of my issues, but I think the other issue begins with the second for loop, i think this is why my program is counting the instances in which the word occurs rather than the line numbers.

Comment: ya, can do, give me a little bit and I'll post another solution

Comment: Thank you for the help!!

Comment: Sorry I did not address your first statement. The way the file is set up is like a .txt file of poems. So the first line is the poem name, \n, author, \n, \n, then the poem (each verse on its respective line).

Comment: are there actually '\n' in the text? in other words, is "poem name, \n, author, \n, \n" on the same line?

Comment: Sorry, \n are the line breaks in the file, so that would be an entire space with no text on it.

Answer (score 0):

per request, I made an additional answer (that I think works) without importing another library

```
def index2(f,word_f):

    infile = open(f, 'r')
    dct = {}
    # deleted line
    for line in infile:
        newLine = line.replace('\n', ' ')
        if newLine == ' ':
            continue
        # deleted line
        newLine2 = removePunctuation(newLine)
        split_line = newLine2.split()
        for word in word_f:
            count = 0 # you might want to start at 1 instead, if you're going for 'word number'
            # important note: you need to have 'word2', not 'word' here, and on the next line
            for word2 in split_line: # changed to looping through data
                if word2 == word:                    
                    if word2 in dct:
                        temp = dct[word]
                        temp.append(count)
                        dct[word] = temp
                    else:
                        temp = []
                        temp.append(count)
                        dct[word] = temp
                count += 1
    for word in word_f:
        print('{:12} {},'.format(word,dct[word]))
    infile.close()
```

Do be aware, I don't think this code will handle if the words passed in are not in the file. I'm not positive on the file that you're grabbing from, so I can't be sure, but I think it'll seg fault if you pass in a word that doesn't exist in the file.

Comment: there's a case that the words passed in won't be in the file. Would you like me to fix the error that would occur?

Comment: The output is quite odd. It does not seem to be pulling the line numbers where the word occurs. I got this for first word input "[11, 11, 11, 5, 5, 5, 8, 8, 8, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7]" I am not sure what that is pulling yet, I'll have to look into it.

Comment: can you provide an example of a small input file

Comment: whoops, just saw an error in my post ... I just edited it, I was using the same 'word' variable twice, now the second one is 'word2' and there is an additional comparison

Comment: Very odd! The code you have above still does not quite give the line numbers. The output now is [11, 5, 8, 4, 3, 5, 7], perhaps we are thinking of doing different things? I adjusted you code to pull the line numbers in the file where the word occurs, but it is duplicating line numbers. Let me post it

Comment: append to your original post and put 5 lines of your file you are reading from, that'd probably be easier anyway

Comment: Thanks! I adjusted my original post and edited your code to pull the line numbers for the words that are found in the file and the test runs are puling the proper(ish) numbers now, but duplicated.

Comment: did you change 'word' to 'word2'?. One of them is wrong.
See my comment under your main post

Answer (score 0):

Note: I took this code from my other post to see if it works, and it seems that it does

```
def index2():

    word_list = ["work", "many", "lots", "words"]
    infile = ["lots of words","many many work words","how come this picture lots work","poem poem more words that rhyme"]
    dct = {}
    # deleted line
    for line in infile:
        newLine = line.replace('\n', ' ') # shouldn't do anything, because I have no newlines
        if newLine == ' ':
            continue
        # deleted line
        newLine2 = newLine # ignoring punctuation
        split_line = newLine2.split()
        for word in word_list:
            count = 0 # you might want to start at 1 instead, if you're going for 'word number'
            # important note: you need to have 'word2', not 'word' here, and on the next line
            for word2 in split_line: # changed to looping through data
                if word2 == word:
                    if word2 in dct:
                        temp = dct[word]
                        temp.append(count)
                        dct[word] = temp
                    else:
                        temp = []
                        temp.append(count)
                        dct[word] = temp
                count += 1
    for word in word_list:
        print('{:12} {}'.format(word, ", ".join(map(str, dct[word])))) # edited output so it's comma separated list without a trailing comma


def main():
    index2()


if __name__ == "__main__":main()
```

and the output:

```
work         2, 5
many         0, 1
lots         0, 4
words        2, 3, 3
```

and the explanation:

```
infile = [
"lots of words",                        # lots at index 0, words at index 2
"many many work words",                 # many at index 0, many at index 1, work at index 2, words at index 3
"how come this picture lots work",      # lots at index 4, work at index 5
"poem poem more words that rhyme"       # words at index 3
]
```

when they get appended in that order, they get the correct word placement position

Comment: If you wanted something else, I'm not sure what it was

Comment: I see what it happening! Thank you for that explanation. What I really am looking for is the line number where the word occurs, not the index in which the word occurs in the line. Think of it like an index in the back of a book.

Comment: all you have to do to change it is move the 'count = 0' line to before the first for loop, and the count += 1 moved out one for loop (inside between the first and second). This should get you the line number

Comment: if you wanted just 'word number' if you just move 'count = 0' to outside the first for loop, then it should indicate how many words into the file until the words appear

Comment: actually the 'word number' post I just made is slightly off ... too late to edit ... if you wanted just 'word number' if you just move 'count = 0' to outside the first for loop, then the placement of 'count += 1' will have to be changed a little bit because it's inside a loop that counts the words passed in. let me know if this is what you want and I should be able to help, but it might have to wait until tomorrow

Comment: again ... I made a typo ... but it's too late to change it, to 'count += 1' the line numbers the count needs to be moved out TWO loops, not one, but it's still between the first and second loop ... That makes sense that you're getting line numbers. It seemes that there are poems that you're working with from our earlier discussions, and those books do tend to have line numbers with them

Comment: I am working on making those tweaks, I am still running into issues trying to make it pull the right line numbers. I appreciate your help and patience though.

Answer (score 0):

My biggest error was that I was not properly adding the line number to the counter. I completely used the wrong call, and did nothing to increment the line number as the word was found in the file. The proper format was dct[word] += [count] not dct[word] += 1

```
def index(filename,word_list):

    infile = open(filename, 'r')
    dct = {}
    count = 0
    for line in infile:
        count += 1
        newLine = line.replace('\n', ' ')
        if newLine == ' ':
            continue
        newLine2 = removePunctuation(newLine)
        split_line = newLine2.split()
        for word in word_list:
            if word in split_line:
                if word in dct:
                    dct[word] += [count]
                else:
                    dct[word] = [count]
    for word in word_list:
        print('{:12} {}'.format(word,dct[word]))
    infile.close()
```